# Send Form value to two destinations

Tags: php, api

My question is I have a form that I want to submit its values to two locations, 1 would be to my networks database and another to a vicidials server that accepts this api, what would be my approach on doing this, I was thinking of php redirect using `header()` after inserting to database, isn't it messy that way? Is there any other way of doing this?

Form -> Database -> This apilink

```
http://serverip/vicidial/non_agent_api.php?phone_number=123456&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&address1=7153+Marbella+Unit+401&city=Cape+Canaveral&state=FL&postal_code=329200000&custom_fields=Y&birth_date=12-25-2017&duplicate_check=DUPCAMP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use file_get_contents:

```
<?php
file_get_contents($url_with_encoded_params);
```

Otherwise you are reliant upon the client's browser doing a redirect after receiving the header instruction, you'll also be exposing the end point, and are prone to possible data manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You can make two functions, one to save the submitted data to the database and one to submit it to the API.

```
function handleForm() 
{
    $data = [
        'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'],
        'first_name'   => $_POST['first_name'],
        // etc ...
    ];
    
    $inserted = insertToDb($data);
    if ($inserted) {
        $api_response = submitToApi($data);
    }

}

function insertToDb($data)
{
    $inserted = false;

    // do stuff to insert data to database

    if (/**stuff went good**/) {
        $inserted = true;
    }
    
    return $inserted; 
}

function submitToApi($data)
{
    $query_string = http_build_query($data);
    $url = 'http://serverip/vicidial/non_agent_api.php?' . $query_string;
    return file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Comment: Beware the "if" statement, however, as you don't want to lose data by not submitting it to the Vicidial server because the DB server failed. If you leave the "if ($inserted) {" in place, that could be the result when the DB server is down or rejects your attempt for whatever reason (my favorite: had a \ in the submitted text ... haven't properly escaped everything yet, lol)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

#### 1. Client side processing

Use ajax call to submit form data to your app server at first then submit same data to third-party API endpoint.

#### 2. Server-side processing

You can simply submit the form to your app server, and then from your app server (after storing data in your database) send a request (may use curl) to third-party API.

I would personally prefer the 2nd one. As it does not exposes the vendor API to the user.